# XPC service, launch as Launch Agent

Tags: cocoa, daemon, launchd, xpc, launch-agent

i did create an XPC service, that runs in background and creates periodical tasks

- placed it into path 
  /Users/Peter/Library/Application Support/AGENT TEST APPS/CS Agent.xpc
- i can run it, by directly executing the file
- i placed a .plist it into the LaunchAgents, refereeing to the executable

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
  <plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
      <key>Debug</key>
      <true/>
      <key>Label</key>
      <string>com.company.CS-Agent</string>
      <key>KeepAlive</key>
      <true/>
      <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
      <key>Program</key>
      <string>/Users/Peter/Library/Application Support/AGENT TEST APPS/CS Agent.xpc</string>
  </dict>
  </plist>
  ```

**but it doesn't launch upon startup as it should**

---

UPDATE

did try to load manually

```
Peters-MacBook-Air:LaunchAgents Peter$ launchctl load com.company.CS-Agent.plist
com.company.CS-Agent: Already loaded
```

But i don't see it in activity monitor, nor any output it should produce (create files)

when i do launchctl list i see

```
-   13  com.company.CS-Agent
```